# In Javascript, what could cause new Date() to return null epoch but Date() returns perfectly valid time?

Tags: javascript, datetime

This one is completely bizarre:: entering `dt = Date(1680907460.)` return April 17th, but  `dt = new Date(1680907460.)` returns the null epoch. Screen snapshot shown below (Chrome).

Am I missing something in the syntax for "new Date" ??

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that `new Date()` needs the timestamp in **milliseconds**. Any date on 20 Jan 1970 is not "the null epoch"

Comment: ```dt = Date(1680907460000)``` returns Mon Apr 17 2023, whereas ```dt = new Date(1680907460000)``` returns  Fri April 7th. 2023.... Getting closer.

Comment: Oh!!! Which is **now**.. That only just sunk in ! :-)

Comment: From [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#return_value) _Any arguments given in a Date() function call (without the new keyword) are ignored_

Comment: Thanks, yes, I see it now. The first command `Date()` just completely ignored the value and  the second command to `new Date()` was expecting milliseconds whereas I was passing seconds. Dumb of me!